# I climb Every Day

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

I awake, refreshed anew.

Looking forward to a new and glorious day, I unfurl and quiver in the cold.
My morning shower wakes me and regales with many succulent droplets; I can feel them invigorate my veins.
I start my work.
I remember to breathe in and out.
As the day unfolds I thirst and deeply drink my fill.
The heat of midday is relentless, but I am virile; I weather the storm.
At day's end I grow tired, but I cling to consciousness.
I find myself once again chilled and shivering.
Eventually I gravitate back to bed, digging deep into the cover.
I dream of my ancestors, remember my roots.
And sleep.

Tomorrow is another day.

Hint:

> Maybe a "day" isn't really a day, and "climb" may suggest something else too.

Comment: Is the question, what you are?

Comment: @Geshode Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> An annual plant

I awake, refreshed anew.

> The plant comes back to life, refreshed and looking new

Looking forward to a new and glorious day, I unfurl and quiver in the cold.

> Looking forward to a new period (year) of living, it comes back to life when it's still cold outside

My morning shower wakes me and regales with many succulent droplets; I can feel them invigorate my veins.

> The morning is the end of winter and start of spring, there's still a lot of rain but that helps the plant to grow and gain strength

I start my work.

> It start's with photosynthesis when big enough

I remember to breathe in and out.

> Breathing in carbon dioxide and breathing out oxygen.

As the day unfolds I thirst and deeply drink my fill.

> The plant tries to fill up on water as much as possible, so it can survive the summer

The heat of midday is relentless, but I am virile; I weather the storm.

> The midday represents the summer. A period with a lot of heat but also a storm from time to time. Only strong and virile plants survive this.

At day's end, I grow tired, but I cling to consciousness.

> The end of the day is autumn. The plant starts to lose its strength but still lives. It's ready to end its life cycle for this year.

I find myself once again chilled and shivering.

> Winter is coming, the cold is back

Eventually, I gravitate back to bed, digging deep into the cover.

> The plant has no strength left and dies, disappearing back into the earth

I dream of my ancestors, remember my roots.

> The plant may be "dead" but the roots are still there, ready for a new cycle. The ancestors are the past lifecycles.

And sleep.

> The roots are asleep all winter

Tomorrow is another day.

> The lifecycle starts anew with a new "day" which represents a new annual cycle.

The hint explained

> The day talked about is the annual cycle from life to "death" covering all the seasons. The climb is the growth of the plant.

Comment: I was actually going for rot13(Qrpvqhbhf gerr yrnirf "ervapneangvat." Tenivgngr jnf fhccbfrq gb or n ovt pyhr). As your answer is just as good, if not better. I'll accept it soon.

Comment: The rot13("zl irvaf") part had thinking about rot13("gerr yrnirf") too but I descided to go with this answer for some reason. Now that I read it again the "Eventually I gravitate back to bed, digging deep into the cover." part makes perfect sense in your case.

Answer (score 5):

It can be:

> Devil's ivy

I awake, refreshed anew.

Looking forward to a new and glorious day, I unfurl and quiver in the cold.

> As all the plants start there daily life-cycle from the morning same is with the Devil's ivy which is more commonly known as money plant vines start their day. Considering that it was a icy night and there was a bit of snowfall we can assume that the plant unfurl itself with the heat of the sun and quivers as it sheds the thin layer of ice which melts down.

My morning shower wakes me and regales with many succulent droplets; I can feel them invigorate my veins.
I start my work.

> We can relate this to people who water their plants in morning and same can be here too as water seeps down to the roots it is absorbed by the plant. And simultaneously they start their  work which can be photosynthesis i guess?

I remember to breathe in and out.
As the day unfolds I thirst and deeply drink my fill.

> Breathe in carbon dioxide and give out oxygen? This can be related to this clue. As the day passes it slowly absorbs water from the roots to fulfill its needs i.e. to perform photosynthesis.

The heat of midday is relentless, but I am virile; I weather the storm.
At day's end I grow tired, but I cling to consciousness.

> As the sun shines in its full might, it continue to be strong performing photosynthesis and giving out oxygen. At the end of the day as it stop getting sun light it slowly stop its work i.e. photosynthesis ?

I find myself once again chilled and shivering.
Eventually I gravitate back to bed, digging deep into the cover.
I dream of my ancestors, remember my roots.
And sleep.

Tomorrow is another day.

> This can be related to the night which once again brings with itself a bit of snowfall and it feels chilled which eventually furls itself.
>  Until the sun rises up the next morning. (Not sure of the latter part)

Title

> Because of the title which says I Climb I came to the solution that it is Devil's ivy because it climbs to the near by objects whether its pole,trees,house or anything and the unfurling thing is something which I've personally seen in my hometown during winters. Although it doesn't snows there but the Leaves in the vine they use to unfurl in the morning and slowly furl back as the night use to fall.

Comment: +1 Not a bad guess, but there's more to it.

Comment: Any hints ? @Chowzen

Comment: Added a hint and a tag: [tag:wordplay].

Answer (score 1):

The answer, to add on to Maniraj's, is:

> Water 'climbing' up the roots, stem, and leaves of a plant.

My morning shower wakes me and regales with many succulent droplets; I can feel them invigorate my veins. I start my work.

> Dew in the morning. The water begins to hydrate the plant, spreading up the xylem and into its leaves through capillary action.

I remember to breathe in and out.

> As Maniraj pointed out, photosynthesis: the plant converts carbon dioxide into oxygen.

The heat of midday is relentless, but I am virile; I weather the storm.

> Evapotranspiration - the water climbs up the plant and even up into the atmosphere.

Eventually I gravitate back to bed, digging deep into the cover.

> "Bed" and "digging" indicate the soil--the water (as dew or another source) falls back into the soil to be absorbed again by the plant's roots the next day.

I dream of my ancestors, remember my roots.

> 'Roots' is one of the biggest clues to the riddle.

Comment: +1, but this is still missing a key element alluded to in the hint.

Comment: Is it the plant living/growing and dying/returning to the soil, so the poem represents the cycle of life as a whole?